# Issue in splitting string using scanner

Tags: java, split, java.util.scanner

I need your help to specify the reason why split function does not work well using `Scanner` in below code:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);   
System.out.println("Please enter event information in format dd/mm/yyyy,dd/mm/yyyy,name,details");
String info = scanner.next();

String[] parts = info.split(",");
System.out.println("length of ararys:" + parts.length);
for (String s : parts) {
  System.out.println(s);
}
```

If the input is the following phrase:

```
15/05/2017,20/05/2017,Java SE Workshop,Java SE workshop with team
```

then output is:

```
length of ararys:3
15/05/2017
20/05/2017
Java
```

I need to store all sentence in arrays by splitting it using comma to be in 4 parts, what is problem in my code??

Comment: What is the output you are getting?

Comment: I need below output not as above:
15/05/2017
20/05/2017
Java SE Workshop
Java SE workshop with team

Comment: Use `nextLine()` instead of `next()`

Comment: Thanks it works well now

Answer (score 0):

Use `String info = scanner.nextLine();` instead of `String info = scanner.next();` to make sure you take input of whole line.`

Answer (score 0):

replace your
`scanner.next()` 
with
`scanner.nextLine()`
go through jdk documentation.

Comment: Please anither help :how to do regular expression  to prompt the user to input in format using  matches function to be like this format: {dd/mm/yyyy,dd/mm/yyyy,name,details}

Comment: `
public static void methodA(){  
  
  Date date = new Date();
  methodB(date);
  
 }
 public static void methodB(Date dt){
  
  DateFormat  sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");  
  String requiredDate = sdf .format(new Date());  
  System.out.println(requiredDate);
  
 }
`
Is that what you require?

Comment: No , what I need using regular expression passed through (matches) method